# NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName: works not properly

Tags: iphone, ios, timezone

The server returns me the right date & time. New York time zone.

`2013-09-10 05:37:07 +0000` (the right time, when comment was posted)

Here's how I format it in the app:

```
[format setDateFormat:@"dd MMM, yyyy HH:mm"];

[format setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"America/New_York"]];
```

And as the result I have

```
10 sept, 2013 01:37
```

What's wrong?

**UPD**

The code

```
    NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [format setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"America/New_York"]];
    [format setDateFormat:@"dd MMM, yyyy HH:mm"];

    NSString *stringDate = [format stringFromDate:Date]; //Date is "2013-09-10 05:37:07 +0000"
    //stringDate is "10 sept, 2013 01:37"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My current time (at that moment) is: 3:00 PM

New York's time (at that moment) is: 8:00 AM

Solution:

```
NSDate *date = activityDate; // Server sends me the date: 2013-09-10 09:00:00 +0000
NSString *dateFormat = @"dd MMM, yyyy HH:mm";
//Then the transformation comes here
NSDateFormatter* newYorkDf = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[newYorkDf setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"America/New_York"]];
[newYorkDf setDateFormat:dateFormat];

NSDateFormatter* gmtDf = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[gmtDf setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
[gmtDf setDateFormat:dateFormat];
NSDate *gmtDate = [gmtDf dateFromString:[newYorkDf stringFromDate:date]];

NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[format setDateFormat:dateFormat];
NSString *stringDate1 = [format stringFromDate:gmtDate];
self.labelDate.text = stringDate1;   // Returns me: 10 Sept, 2013 8:00
```

Answer (score 1):

You said "the server returns". Can you tell us more on how you are getting your original date? 
You are probably building an UTC date and then formatting it as if it was a NY (eastern time zone) one. Easter TZ is UTC-5. I'm guessing you have daylight saving in effect since 5:37 - 5h would give 0:37.

If you post how you are building the original date you are formatting with the code shown, I could probably get more specific.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Actually, the sarver-side-man tells, that he builds the UTC date.

Comment: But when I set timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC" - the difference with NY is 6 hours (should be 7)

Comment: The problem is in how you build the `Date` (better to use lowercase) variable in your code. We don't see it. If you build it by assuming it's UTC then the formatter is doing it's job correctly by shifting it back by 4h. In other words... 5:45 UTC identifies a moment in time regardless of where in the world (or actually the universe hence the name) it is happening. At that instant, if you want to know what time it was in NewYork, the formatter gives you 1:45. If you asked what time it was in Paris, you would get probably 6:45. The problem is before that... when you create the `Date` variable.

Comment: agree with you about code conventions. What about `Date`, I get it from the server in format `2013-09-10 05:37:07 +0000` as it was said before

Comment: That's a `NSString`... how do you convert it into a `NSDate`?

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that the error is on the server side. If they are returning you a string like "2013-09-10 05:37:07 +0000" and they claim it's NewYork time, then it's their fault. The +0000 at the end states that should be UTC time.

Comment: When you convert the +0000 based string in NSDate, you get the moment in history when it was 5:45 in UTC time. For ease of communication let's pretend it's the same thing as in GMT. Thus the NSDate you get is the instant it was 5:45 in England. At that time it was 1:45 in NewYork... that is correct.

Comment: If you do replace the `+0000` string with `EST` (I should try it myself... I'm writing from my car) and then build the NSDate, you would get the correct moment in history.

Comment: So... either the server is returning the wrong time and they a have the clock set to their local time but are using UTC as their timezone, or they are correctly setup, and their output is in UTC. If that is the case, then your code is giving you the correct answer.

Comment: Yes, they did have the time in such format.
Actually - they return me the date, I put it in dbase, then get it from there.